# how can I show the user's image like a function on user model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

When I try to make a function to show the user's avatar I can not solved this error.

I need help! thanks

[image: the image of error]

code:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ....

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }

    public function getAvatar()
    {
        if($this->image->url)
        {
            $image = $this->image->url;
        }else{
            $image = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $this->email ) ) ) . "?d=mp";
        }

        return $image;
    }
}
```

Comment: it means that `$this->image` is `null`

Comment: What conditional do you recommend?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the code to that:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ....

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }

    public function getAvatar()
    {
        if($this->image)
        {
            $image = $this->image->url;
        }else{
            $image = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $this->email ) ) ) . "?d=mp";
        }

        return $image;
    }
}
```